# COnvert xml to json using command line or using shell script

Tags: json, xml, shell, xml-parsing, sh

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"??>
<resources>
  <data id="V701">
    <string name="MSG_V701_ID">V701</string>
    <string name="MSG_V701_TITLE">abc</string>
    <string name="MSG_V701_BODY">This title is currently unable</string>
  </data>
  <data id="V702">
    <string name="MSG_V702_ID">V702</string>
    <string name="MSG_V702_TITLE">Play</string>
    <string name="MSG_V702_BODY">This title is currently unable to play</string>
  </data>
</resources>
```

how to do this using that command line in ubuntu or shell script

Answer (score 1):

There are no native Bash tools that can do that. So you'd have to use a dedicated tool like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).

You didn't explain how you want the JSON to look like, so is something like this...

```
xidel -s input.xml -e '{|//data/{@* :{|string/{@* :text()}|}}|}'
{
  "V701": {
    "MSG_V701_ID": "V701",
    "MSG_V701_TITLE": "abc",
    "MSG_V701_BODY": "This title is currently unable"
  },
  "V702": {
    "MSG_V702_ID": "V702",
    "MSG_V702_TITLE": "Play",
    "MSG_V702_BODY": "This title is currently unable to play"
  }
}
```

...what you're looking for?